# how to insert an object into a cell using JXL api

Tags: java, excel, jxl

how to insert an object into a cell using JXL (Java Excel API) api..

I have a file which is not image.. I want to insert it into a cell of an Excel sheet..

how can I achieve this?? please help...

Comment: If it is "not image", what is it?  Text?  

It'd help a lot if you could include the code up to the point where you're confused.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html). It doesn't answer how to store generic objects in a cell, but I very much doubt excel can handle untyped data anyway. You must know what kind of object it is, and hope JXL has the appropriate binding.